# Get Cassandra Cluster Network IO

Tags: cassandra, jmx

I wanted to get Cassandra metrics, so I enabled JMX server for Cassandra nodes, but I didn't find any property for network IO usage.
There is some property [here](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/metrics.html#streaming-metrics) at Cassandra document for monitoring incoming and outgoing byte, but I can't find them in JConsole MBeans properties, I guess they will appear just when some client read or write data.

Any suggestion for getting Cassandra network IO metrics. Thanks

Comment: the metrics library changed for different versions of cassandra. What version are you using?

Comment: @LHWizard I use apache Cassandra version 3.11.1